# Single word keywords against 2 or 3 word keywords for SEO

Tags: seo, pagerank, keywords

Looking in Google Webmaster tools for my site, the sixth most common keyword is "life". This appears a lot because I mention "artificial life" and in places "second life" in the page text.

I want to increase the relevance of this page in terms of the keywords in the text, not as just "life" on its own, which as you can see, is far to vague to be of use.

How can I increase the ranking of "artificial life" as a keyword instead of just "life" on my site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to focus on one or two keywords for an entire site. Search engines don't rank sites. They rank pages. What that means is you want to focus on the keywords of specific pages. If you want to rank well for a certain keyword, whether it is a one or three word phrase, you need to dedicate a page to content related to that keyword(s). So if you want to have a page rank for "artificial life" you need to create  page about artificial life. If you want your home page to rank for artificial life then you will need to alter your content to focus more on artificial life. This includes altering your internal links to include that phrase in it, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Webmaster Tools shows only single words in the 'most common keywords' feature. If you use life in combination with 'second' or 'artificial' all the time and don't have it as a single words a lot of times, chances are you'll score a lot better in Google for those two-words combos than just the word 'life'.

I have a website about Marilyn Manson, and according to Webmaster Tools 'manson' is my most common word. Searching for it won't show my site, however. Searching for 'marilyn manson' will. It's just how the Webmaster Tools show your keywords, don't worry too much about it.